For quadrilateral, find a point such that if we draw perpendicular lines from it to each side, the intersection points are collinear
Given a quadrilateral $\text{ABCD}$, find a point in the plane such that if we draw perpendicular lines from it to each side of the quadrilateral (we may prolong the sides for this), the intersection points are collinear.
Attempt at solution: I thought of dividing the quadrilateral with its diagonal $\text{AC}$ forming two triangles and then finding points in each circumcircle such that the Simson Lines are the same. But I'm not sure how to find these points after trying for some time now. Also not sure if I'm on the right path.
Any help would be appreciated although I'd prefer a full solution since this seems to be a very difficult problem. Thanks in advance.

Hint:  The reason why your approach didn't work, is that you also had the foot of the perpendicular to $AC$, which isn't required to lie on this line. And in most cases, it does not lie on this line.
So, modify your approach to find 2 triangles, such that the Simson lines result in foot of the perpendiculars to lines $AB, BC, CD, DA$ only.
Hint:    Separately deal with the case where (at least) one set of opposite lines are parallel.

 Let $AB \cap CD = E$, $AD \cap BC = F$.
 Let $P$ be (any) the intersection point of circumcircles $ADE, ABF$, that is not $A$.
 What can we say about the 2 Simpson lines from $P$? Why are they identical?

Notes

Difficulty is in the eye of the beholder, and I think that this hint is sufficient instead of a full solution. If you're stuck, explain what you've tried to do.
Via the converse of Simpson line, further prove that this classification (intersection of circumcircles) is the complete classification of such points that satisfy the conditions. Thus explaining why this approach is natural / obvious.


Thank you for your help, one question... the points ABE are collinear, how do they have a circumcircle? I thought they needed to form a triangle to have a circumcircle

@TheWorkerOfSecrets Because of horrendous typos. Fixed. Ideally don't look at it, and think about this yourself first.

Okay, I did the drawing and you're right, it's clear that this point works in this case. I'm curious as to what we can do when you have (at least) one set of opposite lines are parallel
